# IIS controlling Error Pages files location?

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

This is the setting I see from IIS Manager for [Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1scX.png).
I have put 404.html in my [root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXTez.png).

now, when ever i get 404 error, it read 404.html from my root folder instead of the 404.htm from "Error Pages"

is there a way to fully control it?

Comment: "it read 404.html from my root folder", probably because your web app uses that page (it can override IIS custom error pages). So, if I were you I would learn more about the web app itself first.

Comment: According to your description, you put a 404.html in the root folder, but you just want the original 404 error page in iis, right? and what is the purpose of 404.html in the root folder if you need to use the original 404 error page?